# How to add SD card to store data

Tags: shields, sd-card

I'm new to Arduino and I was wondering how to add an SD card to Arduino so it can store more code and also store files such as text files.

Is there such a shield, and if so, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you asked Google? It knows about ALL the shields. But yes, there are shields. There are lots and lots and lots and lots of shields, breakout boards, dead-bug tutorials, you name it.

Comment: There are 2 things you need to know: SD-card library & https://luckyresistor.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/sd-card2.png

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more a general question...

Comment: On top of that already said, you cannot use the SD card to store code, only data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

[Sparkfun OpenLog](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9530)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good tutorial:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-micro-sd-breakout-board-card-tutorial/intro

This is from adafruit and is for the micro sd card.